# Bootstraping with R, how to find possible bootstrap samples for a given vector

Tags: r, sampling, bootstrap, biostatistics

Consider the vector
`our_names <- c("John","Ciprian","Brian")`

a. List all possible bootstrap samples of our_names.

b. How many boostrap samples of our_names are there? Explain.

c. Conduct 12 bootstrap samples of our_names, print and describe your results.

How  do you find possible bootstrap samples and how to conduct it in R with a similar vector as in question.

Answer (score 1):

A bootstrap sample will be usually of the same size as the original sample, in this case three. Since it'll be a sampling with replacement, each element choice can be either John, Ciprian or Brian. This leaves us with $3^3=27$ choices.

Simply, you can write three nested loops to generate all possible combinations for this particular array; or use `expand.grid` as used in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422945/generate-all-possible-permutations-or-n-tuples).

Comment: Thank you very much. Also can you explain how to bootstrap this vector in R.

Comment: As I mentioned, you can write loops or use `expand.grid` as shown in other post

Comment: @kst1234 is the answer clear for you?